# Problem loading application dependencies on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, random, time, pickle

I am trying to deploy a program to Heroku, but when installing multiple dependencies I get an error:

```
'No matching distribution found for random'
```

Also for `time` and `pickle` dependencies. On the Internet I found that this is due to the fact that they have not been updated, but did not find how to fix it.
The contents of the file `requirements.txt`:

```
telebot
config
random
datetime
pickle
time
```

The contents of the file `Procfile.windows`:

```
bot: python3 bot.py
```

Comment: @Chris Some of the dependencies are installed normally, but the three dependencies I specified are not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many languages, Python ships with a [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) that includes a certain amount of basic functionality out of the box. Most of the dependencies in your `requirements.txt` file are included in this standard library. There is no need to install them yourself.

Remove [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random), [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime), [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle), and [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) from that file. You should be able to `import` and use them automatically. [`telebot`](https://pypi.org/project/telebot/) and [`config`](https://pypi.org/project/config/) are not part of the standard library, so they should stay:

```
telebot
config
```

Your `requirements.txt` should work locally as well as on Heroku. You can install dependencies from it into your current environment by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Additionally, your `Procfile` probably needs to be changed. Without knowing more about your project I can't say for sure, but your process type should probably be `web`, and you may need to use `python` instead of `python3` (though `python3` might work too):

```
web: python bot.py
```

The file should be called `Procfile`, without any file extension.